# Require one of the bold-border tags on new MetaSO questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, asking-questions, meta

Quoting [Bill The Lizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6536/should-suggestion-be-retagged-to-feature-request-on-metaso/6642#6642):

> Every question on meta-* should have one of the bold-border tags, feature-request, bug, discussion, or support.

Should we enforce this when creating a Meta-SO question, with a drop-down menu?  Or if not enforced, at least strongly suggest that the user pick at least one of these tags?

---

**Edit**: [As pointed out below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6647/require-one-of-the-bold-border-tags-on-new-metaso-questions/6651#6651), this actually is enforced.  So my suggestion would be to tell the user before submitting that he must use one of these badges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is required, if you attempt to post without it, you get this message:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be
>   submitted because:
>
> must include one of these tags -- bug
>   feature-request discussion support

As for, should there be drop-down support of this. I do think it would be helpful and more clear, but I don't think it is overly needed, I think the error posting is descriptive enough to help users.

Comment: thanks, i didn't actually try creating one without one of those tags, i just looked to see if there was any indication of it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a big enough issue to warrant some type of change to how the system works, but I don't see any problem with actively encouraging users to pick one. They are pretty useful in breaking down questions into four distinct categories.

Answer (score 1):

The question UI does indicate that these tags are required on all metas now.

(look in the tag input area)